# Need advice for a small database in SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, data-modeling

Im making a simple app for managing food consumption. Im using SQLite and have trouble thinking how the database should be. I was thinking something like this:

```
Food: foodId(pk),catId(fk), foodName, calories, protein, carbohydrates, fat
Category: catId(pk), catName
Diary: entryId, foodId(fk), catId(fk)
```

Im thinking that one category can be assigned to many foods, and many foods can be added to one category. Im not sure about the Diary table, Im thinking you can add a food to the diary and thats it.

Is this a correct way to make the db?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Just making an observation, but _"one category can be assigned to many foods, and many foods can be added to one category"_ is redundant.

Comment: Also, not seeing a need for `catId` in `Diary`.

Comment: sorry fixed. However the title also said need advice. Im not sure if the relationship is correct between the tables. Thanks.

Comment: Uueerdo: Thanks, I see why now(on catId).
Can u elaborate on the one to many relationship u pointed out? I dont understand.

Comment: I think he was just meaning that you said the same thing twice - 1 cat assigned to many foods = many foods assigned to 1 cat. Agree you need to drop the CatID from Diary since you know that from FoodID. One thing missing perhaps is serving size (i.e., how much of that FoodID was consumed)?

Comment: Haha I see it now. Yea of course I forgot units. I had it in the text file version of the app. But does it look good other than that?

Comment: Seems reasonable for a start, but I don't know the intended use or how it might grow in the future. Always better to plan ahead than apply bandaids. ;)

Comment: I wanted to add date functionality so users can check what they ate yesterday or edit if they remember they ate something yesterday but didnt log it etc. Should I just add a date to each diary entry? or is there a better way? currently the db is as it is in the OP.

Comment: Remove catID and add date and quantity to Diary.  Add serving size to Food.  Then you're good to start using it.  You'll enhance it over time, but the relationships are fine.  Rename entryId to DiaryId...it's not the Entry table.